# Save custom data in the Magento cart

Tags: php, magento

I want to add some custom information alongwith each product in the cart. Suppose I add product X to cart, I want that some extra information like color,custom price etc are also saved somewhere in the database so that I can show that custom information with each product in the cart.
Please help it is urgent.

Comment: Have you tried using custom attributes?

Comment: @jprofitt are you talking about product custom attributes? If yes then I cannot use custom attributes in my case.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I suppose the best I can suggest is to look into using the EAV tables and hook into order events.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize `/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` file as you wish.

```
   <?php $cart_item = $this->getItem() ?>
   <?php $_product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($cart_item->getProductId()) ?>
   <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ATTRIBUTE_CODE')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>
```

This is for "select box" and don't forget to change `ATTRIBUTE_CODE` with your real code!

Comment: thanks for your response. I cannot use attributes. The data to be shown is independent of the Magento attributes and is generated when product is added to cart after customer selects some options. The problem is where to save that data permanently. Your solution just tells how to print data on frontend.

Comment: Arvin, you have only one solution to do this (instead of attribute) which is external database connection. Try subesh extension [Magento External Database Connector](http://subesh.com.np/2012/02/magento-external-database-connector-v1-0-0-released/)